# Python - huge memory consumption while parsing folder of CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing, memory

I have several folders, each of them contains many CSV files. I need to parse them to make some plots etc.

The problem is, that memory consumption is huge and after while it skyrockets to cca 3.4GB. I have no idea what's the cause of this behavior, I've never met a memory-related problem with Python before.

I've found [memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler), which gives me this output:

```
Filename: /home/martin/PycharmProjects/readex-radar/fooVisualizer.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   560  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
   561                             def getAllDataClassifiedFromFolder(measuredFuncFolderArg,
   562                                                                yLabelArg,
   563                                                                filenameArgs,
   564                                                                slideshowCreator,
   565                                                                samplesArgs=None):
   566
   567  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB       sampleSourcesInds = {}
   568  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB       summarySourcesAvg = {}
   569  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB       summarySourcesAvgInds = {}
   570  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB       summarySourcesFull = {}
   571    
   572 3342.426 MiB 3049.086 MiB       for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(measuredFuncFolderArg, topdown=True):
   573                                     # Ignorovat skryte slozky kvuli GITu atd.
   574                                     # TODO mozna nebude treba
   575  293.340 MiB -3049.086 MiB           filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
   576  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB           dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if not d[0] == '.']
   577    
   578                                     ##########################
   579                                     # Parsovani jedne slozky #
   580                                     ##########################
   581    
   582                                     # Vsechna data z jedne slozky (funkce na urcitem radku)
   583  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB           folderData = []
   584    
   585                                     # Nacitam parametry dane v nazvu CSV souboru
   586  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB           funcLabelArg = filenameArgs.getFuncLabel()
   587  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB           xLabelArg = filenameArgs.getXLabel()
   588  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB           otherUserArgs = filenameArgs.getConfigLst()
   589    
   590                                     # 'Rozlozim' config argument na jednotlive hodnoty
   591  293.340 MiB    0.000 MiB           keyLst = filenameArgs.getLstOfParams()
   592    
   593 3382.207 MiB 3088.867 MiB           for filename in filenames:
   594                                         # Nactu data
   595 3382.207 MiB    0.000 MiB               p = LabeledCSVParser('{}/{}'.format(dirpath, filename))
   596 3382.207 MiB    0.000 MiB               p.parse()
   597 3382.207 MiB    0.000 MiB               data = p.getDicData()
   598    
   599                                         # Vytvorit a zapsat 'samples', pokud jsou zadany
   600                                         # parametrem 'samplesArgs'
```

We can see, that in lines 572 and 593 memory consumption rises dramatically. Do you have any idea why? I suppose it's something with `os.walk`...

So, have you ever seen this before? And if you have, could you, please, tell me, how to deal with this?

---

I've tried to add an explicit destructor to the `LabeledCSVParser` object, but it has a very little effect on memory. In addition, it appears, that there's no significant memory consumption in `parse()` function.

So, I'll try to inspect iterating through files a little more.

#### Edit 1

```
Filename: /home/martin/PycharmProjects/readex-radar/fooVisualizer.py   

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   100 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB       @profile
   101                                 def parse(self):
   102                                     """
   103                                     Funkce pro parsovani 'ostitkovaneho' CSV.
   104                             
   105                                     Predpoklada CSV ve tvaru:
   106                             
   107                                         # Label 1
   108                                         data1, data2
   109                                         data3, data4
   110                             
   111                                         # Label 2
   112                                         data5, data6
   113                                         data7, data8
   114                                         ...
   115                             
   116                                     Labely se mohou opakovat, ziskane hodnoty
   117                                     se ulozi do ruznych listu ve slovniku __dicData,
   118                                     kde jejich spolecnym klicem bude label.
   119                                     """
   120                             
   121 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB           currentLabel = self.__parsedFile.readline().split('#')[1].strip()
   122 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB           dataBlock = list()
   123 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.__dicData[currentLabel] = list()
   124                             
   125                                     # Ulozim soucasny dataBlock do __dicData pod klic currentLabel
   126                                     # - hodnoty se do tohoto dataBlocku zapisuji pozdeji diky 
   127                                     #   referenci
   128 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB           self.__dicData[currentLabel].append(dataBlock)
   129                             
   130 3272.949 MiB    1.555 MiB           for row in self.__parsedFile:
   131                                         # Kontrola, jestli se jedna o label nebo radek s daty
   132 3272.949 MiB    0.000 MiB               if row.__contains__('#'):
   133                             
   134                                             # Vytvorim novy dataBlock
   135 3271.395 MiB   -1.555 MiB                   dataBlock = list()
   136                             
   137                                             # Zisk nazvu labelu z radku
   138 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB                   tmpLabel = row.split('#')[1].strip()
   139                             
   140                                             # Label se stane 'aktualnim' -  nasledujici
   141                                             # data se budou zapisovat k nemu
   142 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB                   currentLabel = tmpLabel
   143                             
   144                                             # Pokud neni label 'zaevidovany', pridam
   145                                             # jej do __dicData jako klic
   146 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB                   if currentLabel not in self.__dicData.keys():
   147 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB                       self.__dicData[currentLabel] = list()
   148                             
   149 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB                   self.__dicData[currentLabel].append(dataBlock)
   150                                         else:
   151                                             # Pridam rozparsovany radek do aktualniho
   152                                             # bloku dat jako n-tici
   153 3272.949 MiB    1.555 MiB                   dataBlock.append(tuple(row.strip().split(',')))


Filename: /home/martin/PycharmProjects/readex-radar/fooVisualizer.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   558  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
   559                             def getAllDataClassifiedFromFolder(measuredFuncFolderArg,
   560                                                                yLabelArg,
   561                                                                filenameArgs,
   562                                                                slideshowCreator,
   563                                                                samplesArgs=None):
   564                             
   565  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB       sampleSourcesInds = {}
   566  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB       summarySourcesAvg = {}
   567  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB       summarySourcesAvgInds = {}
   568  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB       summarySourcesFull = {}
   569                             
   570 2746.160 MiB 2452.617 MiB       for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(measuredFuncFolderArg, topdown=True):
   571                                     # Ignorovat skryte slozky kvuli GITu atd.
   572                                     # TODO mozna nebude treba
   573                                     #filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
   574                                     #dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if not d[0] == '.']
   575                             
   576                                     ##########################
   577                                     # Parsovani jedne slozky #
   578                                     ##########################
   579                             
   580                                     # Vsechna data z jedne slozky (funkce na urcitem radku)
   581  293.543 MiB -2452.617 MiB           folderData = []
   582                             
   583                                     # Nacitam parametry dane v nazvu CSV souboru
   584  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB           funcLabelArg = filenameArgs.getFuncLabel()
   585  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB           xLabelArg = filenameArgs.getXLabel()
   586  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB           otherUserArgs = filenameArgs.getConfigLst()
   587                             
   588                                     # 'Rozlozim' config argument na jednotlive hodnoty
   589  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB           keyLst = filenameArgs.getLstOfParams()
   590                             
   591  293.543 MiB    0.000 MiB           print('nacitam data')
   592 3271.395 MiB 2977.852 MiB           for filename in filenames:
   593                                         # Nactu data
   594 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               p = LabeledCSVParser('{}/{}'.format(dirpath, filename))
   595 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               p.parse()
   596 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               data = p.getDicData()
   597                             
   598 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               print('zapisuji samples')
   599                                         # Vytvorit a zapsat 'samples', pokud jsou zadany
   600                                         # parametrem 'samplesArgs'
   601 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               if samplesArgs:
   602                                             sampleSourcesInds[filename] = {}
   603                                             for sampleArg in samplesArgs:
   604                                                 prevNumOfSources = slideshowCreator.getNumOfDataSources()
   605                                                 slideshowCreator.createAndAddDataSource(data[sampleArg], 100, True, 0, 2)
   606                                                 sampleSourcesInds[filename][sampleArg] = list(range(prevNumOfSources,
   607                                                                                                     slideshowCreator.getNumOfDataSources()))
   608                             
   609                                         # Ziskam nazvy parametru z nazvu souboru
   610 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               args = filename[0:filename.rfind('.')].split('_')
   611                             
   612 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               print('tvorim slovnik')
   613                                         # Priradim konkretni hodnoty z nazvu CSV souboru
   614                                         # k zadanym parametrum filenameArgs
   615 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               d = {key: (args[i] if i < len(args) else '') for i, key in enumerate(keyLst)}
   616                             
   617                                         # Pridam do slovniku nactena data ze souboru
   618 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               d['Data'] = data
   619                             
   620 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               print('pridavam slovnik do folderData')
   621 3271.395 MiB    0.000 MiB               folderData.append(d)
   622                             
   623                                     ###############################################################
   624                                     # Rozdelim nactena data ze slozky do skupin podle volitelnych #
   625                                     # argumentu (preconditioner, schur complement...)             #
   626                                     ###############################################################
   627 2742.480 MiB -528.914 MiB           print('rozdeluji data do kategorii')
   628                                     # Ulozene prumerne hodnoty yLabel za vsechna
   629                                     # volani funkce
   630 2742.480 MiB    0.000 MiB           folderDataGroupsAvg = {}
   631                             
   632                                     # Ulozene hodnoty yLabel ze vsech volani fce
   633                                     #
   634                                     # TODO mozna bude treba zapsat jako zdroj pro
   635                                     # graf jednotlivych iteraci solveru
   636 2742.480 MiB    0.000 MiB           folderDataGroupsFull = {}
   637                             
   638 2745.746 MiB    3.266 MiB           for i, val in enumerate(folderData):
   639                                         # Ziskam hodnoty konfiguracnich argumentu
   640                                         # a ulozim je jako n-tici
   641 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB               optArgsTup = tuple([str(val[arg]) for arg in otherUserArgs])
   642                             
   643                                         # Pokud jeste neni, pridam n-tici s konfiguracnimi
   644                                         # parametry jako klic pro slovnik s prumernymi
   645                                         # hodnotami spotreby
   646 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB               if optArgsTup not in folderDataGroupsAvg:
   647 2743.320 MiB   -2.426 MiB                   folderDataGroupsAvg[optArgsTup] = {}
   648 2743.320 MiB    0.000 MiB                   folderDataGroupsFull[optArgsTup] = {}
   649                             
   650 2745.746 MiB    2.426 MiB               if folderData[i][funcLabelArg] not in folderDataGroupsAvg[optArgsTup]:
   651 2744.539 MiB   -1.207 MiB                   folderDataGroupsAvg[optArgsTup][folderData[i][funcLabelArg]] = []
   652 2744.539 MiB    0.000 MiB                   folderDataGroupsFull[optArgsTup][folderData[i][funcLabelArg]] = []
   653                             
   654                                         # Fce pro ziskani hodnot z Blade summary,
   655                                         # ktere slouzi jako yLabelArg.
   656                                         # Nepsano jako lambda kvuli fyz. delce kodu funkce.
   657 2745.746 MiB    1.207 MiB               def getYLabelVals(ind):
   658 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                   retLst = []
   659 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                   for subLst in folderData[ind]['Data']['Blade summary']:
   660 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                       for item in subLst:
   661 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                           if item[0] == yLabelArg:
   662 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                               retLst.append(float(item[1]))
   663 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                   return retLst
   664                             
   665                                         # Zapisu hodnoty ze vsech volani fce pro jedno nastaveni
   666                                         # do folderDataGroupsFull
   667 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB               folderDataGroupsFull[optArgsTup][folderData[i][funcLabelArg]] \
   668 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                   .append((folderData[i][xLabelArg], getYLabelVals(i)))
   669                             
   670                                         # Ziskam prumernou spotrebu ze vsech volani fce pro jedno
   671                                         # nastaveni (Prec, Schur) a jeden popisek funkce
   672                                         # (pocet jader...).
   673                                         #
   674                                         # TYTO UDAJE PRIDAM do folderDataGroupsAvg.
   675 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB               folderDataGroupsAvg[optArgsTup][folderData[i][funcLabelArg]] \
   676 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB                   .append((folderData[i][xLabelArg], numpy.mean(getYLabelVals(i))))
   677                             
   678 2745.746 MiB    0.000 MiB           print('zapidu folderDataGroupsAvg jako zdroj')
   679                                     # Ziskani dat z folderDataGroupsAvg a jejich zapis jako zdroje
   680 2746.160 MiB    0.414 MiB           for key, vals in sorted(folderDataGroupsAvg.items()):
   681 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB               summarySourcesAvg[key] = {}
   682                             
   683                                         # TODO promyslet, jestli nebude lepsi sloucit summarySourcesAvg a summarySourcesAvgInds
   684                                         # do jednoho slovniku
   685 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB               summarySourcesAvgInds[key] = {}
   686                             
   687 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB               for subKey, val in sorted(vals.items()):
   688                                             # Zapisu do listu zdroje pro danou konfiguraci - pro vypocty procent atd.
   689 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB                   summarySourcesAvg[key][subKey] = val
   690                             
   691                                             # Zapisu data do zdroju pro vykreslovani grafu
   692 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB                   summarySourcesAvgInds[key][subKey] = slideshowCreator.getNumOfDataSources()
   693 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB                   slideshowCreator.createAndAddDataSourcesTexCode([sorted(val)], 0, False, 0, 1)
   694                             
   695 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB           print('ziskam data z folderDataGroupsFull')
   696                                     # Ziskani dat z folderDataGroupsFull
   697                                     #
   698                                     # TODO mozna bude potreba i zapis zdroju pro
   699                                     # grafy jednotlivych iteraci
   700 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB           for key, vals in sorted(folderDataGroupsFull.items()):
   701 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB               summarySourcesFull[key] = {}
   702                             
   703 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB               for subKey, val in sorted(vals.items()):
   704                                             # Zapisu do listu zdroje pro danou konfiguraci - pro vypocty procent atd.
   705 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB                   summarySourcesFull[key][subKey] = val
   706                             
   707 2746.160 MiB    0.000 MiB       return summarySourcesAvg, sampleSourcesInds, summarySourcesAvgInds, summarySourcesFull
```

Comment: Are you making an effort to `del` any objects you no longer require?

Comment: @MaxUppenkamp I've tried to delete the parser object p (line 595), but I've always thought, that Python has a pretty good garbage collector :-)

Comment: You use **filenames** in several spots.  Python lists are mutable so having a filename that comes in through os.walk and is then reused to mean something else?  The other thing you could do is comment out the parser stuff in 595-597.  If you still have issues, you should look at the filenames and os.walk.  If you don't then you need to find a way to make the parser stuff use less memory.

Comment: @JLPeyret I've tried adding destructor to the parser object and I've done another profiling, this time with parser - info added to the question.

Comment: Have you tried `pandas`?  Pandas dataframes take less space and support a batch mode out of the box?

Comment: What if you dont have a parser object?  I know, pointless for your goals, but *is* mem consumption coming from there or not?  Don't overfocus on profilers, amputate some of your code to get the big picture. You should at least diff between your os.walk and the parser as the cause.   Also what is the volume of files/dirs you are talking about?  Last, what/where is LabeledCSVParser coming from?  Your own?